# How decrypt YouTube TLSv1.2 traffic by using Man-In-The-Middle proxy?

Tags: youtube, wireshark, mitmproxy, man-in-the-middle

I use my laptop as a Man-In-The-Middle proxy. Then I open YouTube from a PC through the laptop. I captured the transferred traffic on the laptop.
I want to capture YouTube traffic and understand video traffic. How can I decrypt the captured file?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to bounce the SSL certificate using a Proxy. A quick and dirty way to test this is to use "Fiddler". If you want a more robust solution, check out Squid. It supports SSL stripping.